# Unable to make custom action for UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have problem with `UITabBar`. I need to make a custom action for `Item` (`UITabBarItem`). What do I need to add to make it working?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var TabBar: UITabBarItem!
@IBOutlet var Item: UITabBarItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar!, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {

    var selectedTag = tabBar.selectedItem?.tag
    println(selectedTag)

    if selectedTag == 0
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since the view changes to a new view when you tap the UITabBarItem, can you just put your code in the func viewDidLoad() for each of the views?

Comment: I move func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar!, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) into viewDidLoad() and still nothing. I need to make this function working

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean put the function within the function.  Just put your execution code in the viewDidLoad function. But that is also a mistake.  You want the viewWillAppear() - i will post code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each ViewController place this function:

```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //set inital view

    }
```

Then put your code to execute in here and when the view appears it will execute.

Okay then, what I think you want then is not a UITabBar but instead a UIToolBar.  From Apple:

"A tab bar is a control, usually appearing across the bottom of the screen in the context of a tab bar controller, for giving the user one-tap, modal access to a set of views in an app. Each button in a tab bar is called a tab bar item and is an instance of the UITabBarItem class. If you instead want to give the user a bar of buttons that each perform an action, use a UIToolbar object."

For the UIToolBar description see:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIToolbar

Comment: Thanks for tip but i need to make only custom action (something like button but in UITabBar) i dont need to go to the other ViewController.

Comment: can i get contact to you? I need to ask something but its secret (my project is top secret)

Comment: I know it but at first time i get error and i was suprised. Can you give me any contact?

Comment: Mathflash.iphone gmail